# Refactoring validation methods and callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, refactoring

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I have tree classes what behavior is almost the same (and also the code in them model files). All those have a `name` and a `description` attribute, run same validation methods and for both there is a `before_save` callback that maintains data consistent providing the same functions.

*I would like to refactor validation methods and callbacks in a separated class\model* (I think I have to locate them related files in the `\lib` folder of my application).

**What I have to do to make that? What code I have to add in my classes and what in the refactoring class\model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just make a super class from which your three models inherit. I tend to put the abstract base class in app/models alongside the models themselves.

```
# app/models/thing.rb
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
    # common code goes here, such as
    before_save ...
    validates_length_of :foo
end

# app/models/red_thing.rb
class RedThing < Thing
    # methods specific to RedThing go here
end

# app/models/blue_thing.rb
class BlueThing < Thing
    # methods specific to BlueThing go here
end
```

If your Things have many differences such that it doesn't make sense to group them like this, you'd want to use a module instead, which is a only bit more complicated.

Comment: Davis - Can you make me an example using modules?

Comment: What trouble did you run into when you tried something similar with modules?

Answer (score 0):

Rails guides has info here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods

Comment: Paul Groves - That is for validation purposes... and what for callbacks? Furthermore, I would like to keep all "refactored code" in the separated class\model.

Comment: Apologies… promise, no more comments without reading the question properly :(

FWIW - @rob-davis' answer looks good to me, I have done the same thing when creating multiple classes which ran from a different database.